# Unresolved dependency when trying to install SecureSocial in Play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, securesocial

First steps with Scala and with Play. I'm trying to install the SecureSocial plugin, but I can't. I'm interested in the resolution itself, and anything (answer or resources) than can improve my knowledge of the tools.

In the Scala webpage (http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html) instructions are:

- To include the module in your project add the following dependency to your Build.scala file:
- "securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.2"
- Resolver: "http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"

And that's the first problem. I don't have Build.scala. Anyway, I have a /project/plugins.sbt that has a very similar structure.

Even with a different format, I'm able to put the lines:

- resolvers += "Social login" at "http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"
- addSbtPlugin("securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.2")

When I try to compile, an enormous exception stack appears. Basically:

- sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: securesocial#securesocial;2.1.2: not found

Seems to be trying:

- http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/securesocial/securesocial_2.10_0.13/2.1.2/securesocial-2.1.2.pom

If I check http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, I can't see anything similar to the path previously written. For example, you can see, where docs and source is placed, but in JAR format, not pom:

- http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/securesocial/securesocial_2.10/2.1.2/

Am I doing it completely wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SecureSocial uses an [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)-Style repository, not [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) style. Hence, you have to declare your resolver to use Ivy style:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases", 
    new URL("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))
    (Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

(line breaks added for readability)

Maven and Ivy dictate different directory structures. SBT supports both, but defaults to Maven style. So if you want to use a repository that uses another directory structure, you have to tell sbt which structure that is.

Furthermore,

```
addSbtPlugin("securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.2")
```

is not the right choice to include dependencies - it is used to include plugins for sbt itself. Instead, use

```
libraryDependencies += "securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.2"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really. Every one of your comments its important to fix the situation. Now it's compiling and I've felt as if the module has been downloaded but, I can't find it int the project and I can't import securesocial.core_. Can you help me?

Comment: Libraries are downloaded to ~/.ivy2/cache/, not the project directory.  Also, you don't have to compile Play projects manually, just open the web page. Besides that, I can't help you, and you should probably open another question since it is not really really related to this one

Comment: Absolutely Mef, I didn't know if it could be related or not. Really, thanks. As I said, every point you made in your answer is important. Seems that If I add a Build.scala just as in the instructions (even if Play doesn't make one by default) it works.

Comment: fyi, I noticed that the SecureSocial documents list a version 2.1.3, but there is no version 2.1.3 in the ivy repo, only 2.1.2.  That tripped me up.

Comment: Starting 2.1.3 SecureSocial is published to Maven Central. @TimCull you probably saw the site before I updated the docs.